# plotting real time data

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want process the data from some ros nodes and make a real time plot, preferably using matplotlib. What is the easiest way to do this?

For example if I would like plot the average of two values in the ros network, or add a legend to the plot. I know about rqt_plot, but its usefulness is very limited since it can only plot already defined messages.. and you can't even change the axis limits afaik!

Any tips? The best thing would be if there was a way to continually update a matplotlib figure and have it displayed as the roscore is running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264767/plotting-real-time-data/) by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-26**:
Take a look at https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler - I haven't tried it yet but I'd like to hear if it addresses some of your needs.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2017-06-30**:
There is an infinity of answers on stackoverflow treating the continuous update of a matplotlib figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up doing the following. It works in real time as long as pyplot can keep up with the messages.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import rospy
from qualisys.msg import Subject

def plot_x(msg):
    global counter
    if counter % 10 == 0:
        stamp = msg.header.stamp
        time = stamp.secs + stamp.nsecs * 1e-9
        plt.plot(msg.position.y, msg.position.x, '*')
        plt.axis("equal")
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.00000000001)

    counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0

    rospy.init_node("plotter")
    rospy.Subscriber("position_measurements", Subject, plot_x)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    rospy.spin()
```

---

Originally posted by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) with karma: 98 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dei](https://answers.ros.org/users/71483/dei/) on 2021-03-05**:
I, ve tried this program, but I have an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./subscriber_sniffer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from qualisys.msg import Subject
ImportError: No module named qualisys.msg
```

Have you got any suggestion?

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-05-21**:
Yes, because you do not have probably a ROS package named `qualisys`. You probably also do not need it because to try this code, you need a node that is publishing messages of the type `Subject` from this package `qualisys`. I replaced that line with `nav_msgs/Odometry` like this:

`from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry`

This is because the things I want to live plot as are published on the topic `/odom` of the above mentioned message type. Remeber to also change the `position_measurements` with your topic name in `rospy.Subscriber(...)`

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-05-21**:
@linusnie the solution works beautifully. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did liveplotting in the past in two ways:

Your prefered way is the matplotlib so thats pretty easy and I explain a little bit more:

There you need a `animation.FuncAnimation`. It makes an animation by repeatedly calling a function/method. You can read more [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html).

Furter in the repeatedly called function you should do something like:

```
xdata.append(frame)
ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
```

so there you append new data and than set it. What you now need to do different is that you setup a ROS Subscriber to your data you want to publish and in the callback function/method you need to append the new data and just set in the
repeatedly called function the new data. Thats only a close look about how you can do it to give you an idea.

The other way is using c++ and writing for example a rviz plugin with QT. I prefere here the [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/realtimedatademo) for live plotting. But thats a little bit tricky and needs more time when you have no idea about QT. But for me it generates better looking plots and when you are used to it its very easy too.

When you need further help please ask! It isnt too detailed. Just to give you an idea.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) on 2017-06-27**:
this works! but I've always found FuncAnimation to be cumbersome to work with. If anyone has other ideas I'm still interested

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2020-03-28**:
qcustomplot is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many tools to plot.

**- rqt_plot**

**- rqt_multiplot (from ethz)** tool is quite nice to use (compared to rqt_plot)

**-plot_juggler** this is my favourite tool its so fast plotting data and so easy to use! Try it yourself!

**Install:**

sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-plotjuggler

**Run it:**

- rosrun plotjuggler PlotJuggler
- Go to streaming and start ros_topic_streaming
- simply select your topics you wanna stream

Start in launch file:

```
<!-- start plotjuggler -->
<node pkg="plotjuggler" type="PlotJuggler" name="my_plot_Juggler" args="" />
```

If anyone knows how to start from launch file a saved layout.xml  Would be great for sharing :)

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2018-01-30**:
Hi, thanks for recommending PlotJuggler (I am the author). I super appreciate it.

PlotJuggler uses old fashion command line arguments instead os ros params. Display them with -h. You can do:

**Comment by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on 2018-01-31**:
Yeah I saw that --layout our just -l option but it does not work for me If I start gazebo paused.I get cannot find curve with ... error. And if I just run the sim. for a small amount of time and then try to load my layout I get the streamer named ROS Topic Streamer cannot be loaded.

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2018-02-02**:
If you can describe in more detail the problem and/or the desired behavior here, https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler/issues
I will be happy to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since this is an old post and still seems to be active in the community, I am going to provide an example, in general, how can we do real-time plotting. Here I used matplotlib [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rospy
import tf
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from tf.transformations import quaternion_matrix
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


class Visualiser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')
        self.x_data, self.y_data = [] , []

    def plot_init(self):
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 10000)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-7, 7)
        return self.ln
    
    def getYaw(self, pose):
        quaternion = (pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y, pose.orientation.z,
                pose.orientation.w)
        euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(quaternion)
        yaw = euler[2] 
        return yaw   

    def odom_callback(self, msg):
        yaw_angle = self.getYaw(msg.pose.pose)
        self.y_data.append(yaw_angle)
        x_index = len(self.x_data)
        self.x_data.append(x_index+1)
    
    def update_plot(self, frame):
        self.ln.set_data(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        return self.ln


rospy.init_node('lidar_visual_node')
vis = Visualiser()
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/dji_sdk/odometry', Odometry, vis.odom_callback)

ani = FuncAnimation(vis.fig, vis.update_plot, init_func=vis.plot_init)
plt.show(block=True)
```

---

Originally posted by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) with karma: 36 on 2020-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1